# Unnest group of string across columns but keep them in the original row in R

Tags: r, function, purrr, dplyr

I'm trying to find a way to unnest the group of string across columns but keep all the string in the original row. Take the example dataset `starwars` from `dplyr` as it has similar strcuture of my dataset.

The `starwars` dataset has 3 nested columns of `films`, `vehicles`, `starships`. The common approach is to do a `unnest_longer` so we unnest the group of string into multiple rows - each row contains one piece of the string. However, I'd prefer to keep all the ungrouped string in the original row.

The alternative approach is to use `rowwise()` and `mutate` with `paste`. This works but my dataset has 15 nested columns so I'd have to type 15 line of mutate with paste. That's a bit tedious.

```
df <- dplyr::starwars %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(films = paste(films, collapse=', '),
         vehicles = paste(vehicles, collapse=', '),
         starships = paste(starships, collapse=', '))
```

My current thinking is to come up with a wrap function and perhaps I can do it through `purrr` at scale. But my poor function writing is not working - perhaps I am not too familiar with the dplyr hood.

```
ungroup_string <- function(data, x){
  a <- rowwise(data)
  a %>% mutate(x = paste(x, collapse=','))
}
```

Any way I can do this ungroup string across a number of columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `across` :

```
library(dplyr)

starwars %>%
  select(name, films, vehicles, starships) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(across(c(films,vehicles, starships), toString))

#    name       films                                vehicles         starships                             
#   <chr>      <chr>                                <chr>            <chr>                                 
# 1 Luke Skyw… The Empire Strikes Back, Revenge of… "Snowspeeder, I… "X-wing, Imperial shuttle"            
# 2 C-3PO      The Empire Strikes Back, Attack of … ""               ""                                    
# 3 R2-D2      The Empire Strikes Back, Attack of … ""               ""                                    
# 4 Darth Vad… The Empire Strikes Back, Revenge of… ""               "TIE Advanced x1"                     
# 5 Leia Orga… The Empire Strikes Back, Revenge of… "Imperial Speed… ""                                    
# 6 Owen Lars  Attack of the Clones, Revenge of th… ""               ""                                    
# 7 Beru Whit… Attack of the Clones, Revenge of th… ""               ""                                    
# 8 R5-D4      A New Hope                           ""               ""                                    
# 9 Biggs Dar… A New Hope                           ""               "X-wing"                              
#10 Obi-Wan K… The Empire Strikes Back, Attack of … "Tribubble bong… "Jedi starfighter, Trade Federation c…
# … with 77 more rows
```

`across` accepts tidy-select variables. So you don't have to specify each of your 15 columns one by one. You can select column names by position `1:15`, by range `col1:col15` or by some pattern in their name `starts_with('col')`.

Comment: Thanks it works. The range part `col1:col15` is exactly what I want. For `starts_with('col')`, I tried `mutate(across(starts_with('films'), toString))`, it only unnested the `films` and left others nested. I thought it meant "starting at the column to the end". Did I get the wrong idea?

Comment: No, it means all the columns that start with 'film' in the name. If you want to select columns that starts with `film` till the end use `films:last_col_name`.